# updating outer variable inside angular forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I am trying to update an outer variable inside angular forEach. Here is the code.

```
var resultMap = {};   
angular.forEach(originalMap, function(value, key) { 
   resultMap[key] = value; 
  }, resultMap);
console.log(resultMap);
```

Do not know why `resultMap` is empty even after executing forEach block. Is there anything I am missign here?

Update --
For simplicity I have not mentioned the entire code here. Inside the forEach I will write some conditions to fill the resultMap.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to clone object so use `angular.copy` instead `angular.forEach`

```
var resultMap  = angular.copy(originalMap);
```

If you still want to use for-each

```
angular.forEach(originalMap, function (value, key) {
      this[key] = value; //change resultMap to this
  }, resultMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how you check but your code only working here fine. check below link

```
var resultMap = {};   
var originalMap = {
    id: 20,
    email: 'some@some.com'
};
angular.forEach(originalMap, function(value, key) { 
   resultMap[key] = value; 
  }, resultMap);
console.log(resultMap);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fk81z5du/)